# Execute JavaScript code multiple times in different threads when the class is used by multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multithreading, performance

I have a JavaScript code that will execute, lets say when the ID `#script-name` is used. I'm in the scenario where I want to execute it multiple times in different threads when the identifier is used by multiple, lets say by two HTML elements. So, I'd refactored `#script-name` into the class `.script-name`. Lets say I have this code:

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName('script-name')[0]) {
  var obj = $(".script-name");
  obj.animate({
    marginLeft: obj.css("height")
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="script-name" style="height: 25px; background-color: red;">height 25px</div>
<div class="script-name" style="height: 50px; background-color: blue;">height 50px</div>
```

That code will animate both elements to `marginLeft: "25px"`, where I want the second element to animate based on its own `marginLeft: obj.css("height")`. Is there a way to achieve this without creating another identifier with another block of code like this?

```js
if (document.getElementById('script-name')) {
  var obj = $("#script-name");
  obj.animate({
    marginLeft: obj.css("height")
  });
}

if (document.getElementById('script-name-2')) {
  var obj = $("#script-name-2");
  obj.animate({
    marginLeft: obj.css("height")
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="script-name" style="height: 25px; background-color: red;">height 25px</div>
<div id="script-name-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: blue;">height 50px</div>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the use of jQuery and the native DOM lookup methods? `$(".script-name")` does basically the same thing as `getElementsByClassName()`, so why do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.each()` to work on each element in sequence:

```
$(".script-name").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.animate({
    marginLeft: $this.css("height");
  });
});
```

Note that there's really no need to check whether any elements with class "script-name" exist; if none do, then the above code will do nothing without causing any sort of runtime error.

Comment: It looks like you got the answer, I'm familiar with `.each()`.

Comment: @5ervant I checked the documentation to make sure that `.animate()` doesn't allow property values to be functions; it doesn't. Some jQuery functions *do* allow for that sort of thing, and that allows you to skip `.each()`, but then there's really nothing terribly ugly about `.each()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.each() to do that. And `$(selector).somefn()` usually doesn't throw a null pointer so you can get rid of the null check

```js
$("#script-name-2,#script-name").each(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    marginLeft: $(this).css("height")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="script-name" style="height: 25px; background-color: red;">height 25px</div>
<div id="script-name-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: blue;">height 50px</div>
```